# Is there a way to export custom developed Chart (Chart was developed using Chart.js) to PDF without using any other library

Tags: lightning, pdf, dashboard, charts, custom-reports

I have developed a bar chart using Chart.js library in lighting as standard dashboard doesn't help me to meet my requirements. I want to export to PDF without using any other library.
I tried converting canvas to image(canvas.toDataURL method) and store it in attachment object and retrieve later in PDF. But got an exception (too long url to convert)

Is there a way to export customized chart to PDF.

Comment: Am not exactly sure, but I read somewhere that Html2canvas can be used to screenshot screen and save as image. http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

Comment: Salesforce's only PDF generation functionality is `renderAs="pdf"` on a Visualforce page. If that doesn't work for your use case - and I would be rather surprised if it did - you'll need to use some other type of functionality, whether that's another library, a document generation app, or an off-platform service.

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce's only PDF generation functionality is built around Visualforce pages. A Visualforce page can be set to `renderAs="pdf"` to always generate PDFs, or you can render a specific Visualforce page references as a PDF using the `getContentAsPDF()` method (which, incidentally but importantly, counts as a callout).

It's important to know as well that the PDF rendering library used by Salesforce is old and quirky, and lacks support for some modern web standards. I don't believe it supports JavaScript at all, although I cannot say I've tried it myself.

Put shortly, I don't think you have much in the way of options besides using another library, a document generation application, or an off-platform PDF service.

Comment: Thank you David. Visual force doesn't work with javascript chart rendering. Looking options for libraries now.

Answer (score 0):

There are not much options are there. you can try client side pdf rendering.
Using DomToImage & jsPDF to generate PDF.
check this out -> [pdf generate](https://csrviswa.medium.com/salesforce-lightning-how-to-generate-pdf-with-charts-and-images-f10f5dfef45e)

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple JS lib to achieve this.

Chartjs - To render charts.

DomTOIMage - To convert chart canvas to Image

jsPDF - To create pdf and attach images

[Check this post](https://csrviswa.medium.com/salesforce-lightning-how-to-generate-pdf-with-charts-and-images-f10f5dfef45e)